# Makefile:48: recipe for target 'htpasswd' failed

Tags: makefile, pcre, linux-mint, apache2.4, apr

I am trying to install Apache2 on Linux. I downloaded the latest Apache, apr, and apr-util. I am currently trying to run the `make` command on terminal, but there is an error message. See below.

I had tried to do: (from other sources, tried googling this, but it didn't solve the problem)

- go to the root and try it. Same error.
- `apt-get install apache2`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`
- sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev

Here is the console output with errors at the bottom:

```
dfi@dfi-HP-Compaq-6005-Pro-SFF-PC ~/httpd-2.4.33 $ make
Making all in srclib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib'
Making all in apr
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr'
Making all in apr-util
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib'
Making all in os
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os'
Making all in unix
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os/unix'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os/unix'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os/unix'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os/unix'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/os'
Making all in server
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server'
Making all in mpm
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm'
Making all in event
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm/event'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm/event'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm/event'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm/event'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server/mpm'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/server'
Making all in modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules'
Making all in aaa
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/aaa'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/aaa'
Making all in cache
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/cache'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/cache'
Making all in core
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core'
Making all in database
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/database'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/database'
Making all in debugging
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/debugging'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/debugging'
Making all in filters
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters'
Making all in http
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/http'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/http'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/http'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/http'
Making all in loggers
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/loggers'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/loggers'
Making all in metadata
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/metadata'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/metadata'
Making all in proxy
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy'
Making all in session
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/session'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/session'
Making all in slotmem
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/slotmem'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/slotmem'
Making all in proxy/balancers
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy/balancers'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy/balancers'
Making all in arch/unix
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/arch/unix'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/arch/unix'
Making all in dav/main
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/main'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/main'
Making all in generators
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/generators'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/generators'
Making all in dav/fs
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/fs'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/fs'
Making all in mappers
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/mappers'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules/mappers'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/modules'
Making all in support
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/support'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/support'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread         -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo       /home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la /home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'htpasswd' failed
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/support'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/support'
/home/dfi/httpd-2.4.33/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

EDIT: I found out what is wrong. I need to install GNU autoconf and GNU libtool.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev` (looks like [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/apr-dev/201706.mbox/%3CCAJtcoLauYUCHERDucRLG-EAm839cTD6D2x0QWUuEvHYEHS-mDg@mail.gmail.com%3E) is a similar problem)

Comment: I forgot I did that before. So, it did not work.

Comment: Found out what's wrong. I had to install GNU autoconf and GNU libtool.

Answer (score 0):

### Debian

Autoconf:

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ sudo wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xf autoconf*
$ cd autoconf-2.69
$ sudo sh configure --prefix /usr/local
$ sudo make install
```

Automake

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ sudo wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.15.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xf automake*
$ cd automake-1.15
$ sudo sh configure --prefix /usr/local
$ sudo make install
```

Libtool

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ sudo wget http://mirror.jre655.com/GNU/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xf libtool*
$ cd libtool-2.4.6
$ sudo sh configure --prefix /usr/local
$ sudo make install
```

**And after installing the previous packages I reconfigure if the error persists, before compiling and installing**. This is what made me work.

```
$ sudo sh configure --prefix /usr/local/apache2
$ sudo make install
```

---

With these commands, the following errors are solved:

- Makefile:48: recipe for target 'htpasswd' failed
- /httpd/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/638558/676466)

Answer (score 0):

Please check systemctl status httpd (if you installed httpd already)
and you run command:
dnf remove httpd
and you remove source rm -rf /home/root/httpd-2.4.33
and you wget https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache2

Answer (score 0):

This message appears when `apr` and `apr-util` are not installed correctly.
When I compile from a source file and get the same symptoms, I get a message such as `"apr_file_printf" not found`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).